# Slack integration on Bitbucket server

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I cannot see Webhook function on Bitbucket server. The view is different from the Bitbucket on Cloud. The main goal of mine is i am trying to integrate Slack to get all updates from Bitbucket. Could anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

To do this you will need to install the '[Slack Notifications Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.pragbits.stash.stash2slack/server/overview)'.

BitBucket server works on a 'add additional functionality as you need it' model, whereas BitBucket cloud has to cater to a large number of possible user needs where users don't have admin to install the plugins themselves.

To setup: navigate to the [custom integrations tab on the Apps admin page in Slack](https://my.slack.com/apps/manage/custom-integrations), then select 'Incoming Webhooks', 'Add configuration', choose a channel and hit add. You should now have a webhook URL copy this. (you can come back and change the appearance of your webhook user later on or edit it now)

Take the URL you copied, and go to the admin page for your repository in BitBucket server, click 'Slack settings'. Select the events you want to receive messages for, if you want to receive notifications for commits then tick the **Push notifications** option. Enter the channel name you want to post to including the `#` e.g. `#git` and paste in your Webhook URL. Save.

Now when you push a commit to BitBucket you should get a message in the specified Slack channel.

Comment: I installed it and testes with several commits but nothing happens. Do you know what is the problem? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user2210620 Have you setup a webhook in the Slack UI?

Comment: @user2210620 I just re-ran through setup and documented the process above for you.

Comment: I try all the steps you note, but got nothing in the slack channel

Answer (score 0):

The official [Bitbucket Server integration for Slack](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1220729/bitbucket-server-for-slack-official), developed by Atlassian, is now released with Data Center support. You can try it out right now.

<sup>*Disclaimer: I work for Atlassian.*</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately this requires the server be accessible from the internet.  Perhaps the webhook method does as well, as I am having the same issue using webhooks (our server in HTTP but behind a VPN so internal only)